# Flask returns error: Lost connection to MySQL server, system error: 60

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to connect my FLASK app with MySQL on localhost(127.0.0.1:5000) but getting below error.

```
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60")
```

I am using "flask_mysqldb" library. When i tried to fill form and hit submit. it tries to connect to db but never got success and returns error.

Please check out my code and help.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, session, logging
from data import Articles
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL 
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt


app = Flask("__name__")

# config MySQL
app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
app.config["MYSQL_PORT"] = 5000
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "myflaskapp"
app.config["MYSQL_CURSORCLASS"] = "DictCursor"

# init MySQL
mysql = MySQL(app)



Articles = Articles()


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

@app.route("/articles")
def articles():
    return render_template("articles.html", articles = Articles)

@app.route("/article/<string:id>/")
def article(id):
    return render_template("article.html", id=id)

# collect and validate user data
class RegisterForm(Form):
    name        = StringField('Name', [validators.Length(min=1, max=50)])
    username    = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email       = StringField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=50)])
    password    = PasswordField('Password', [
            validators.DataRequired(),
            validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Password do not match')
        ])
    confirm     = PasswordField('Confirm Password')

# insert user data to DB
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name        = form.name.data
        email       = form.email.data
        username    = form.username.data
        password    = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))

        # create cursor(handler) to connect DB
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))

        # commit to db
        mysql.connection.commit()

        # close the connection
        cur.close()

        flash('You are now Registered', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Below are the versions i am using.

- Python: 3.6
- MySQL: 5.7.21

Q: Is "flask_mysqldb" support python 3.6 or not?

Q: What is the good alternative, if required?

- PyMySQL
- mysqlclient
- SQLalchemy

And yes, mysqlclient is also installed already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of these troubleshoots you can try (these are independent steps: So try (1), check if it works, try (2), check if it works and so on...) -

1. Try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` (thats it!)
2. Setting `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in mysql/my.cnf. It basically listens to all addresses (but still one port) then.

And don't forget restart your server: `systemctl restart mysql`

3. Database directory read-write permission. Just make sure your application is able to rw files on db location. Try `chmod 777` for testing.

Let me know if any of this works. If it doesn't, post the error and we can try something.

**Note**: It is a database level problem not a python problem. Check [this](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,151255,213970#msg-213970) `mysql` forum thread for more clues.

Comment: Aahh ,,,  Thank you @Vivek solution 1 runs successfully. Its being whole day i was stuck at this point.

Comment: i did not change any of the other option and my app is working fine. Please tell me that should i change those options to or just leave it as it is for further work ???

Comment: If it works then why bother. Most of the time its reason number 1, hence its listed up top. Cheers!