# lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 60

Tags: mysql, vmware, nat

I installed a centos7 virtual machine in vmvare, then installed docker and docker-compose inside, and built a mysql container, opened the port, and set up a remote connection. The network mode set by the virtual machine is nat mode, And use nat to map the port of mysql. When connecting to mysql, the error "`lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 60`" occurs. I don't know what the situation is. Can you help me? Looking for a problem? thanks

Comment: could you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971396/flask-returns-error-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-system-error-60

Comment: Looks like a packet filter or similar firewall mechanism silently dropping packets, but that's just a blind educated guess